How to use JavaScript or jQuery to select an anchor tag using the enter key
I'm stuck trying to select an anchor tag inside of an unordered list using the keyboard arrow keys and hitting the enter key. The arrow keys will highlight the link, triggering the native browser behavior text-decoration:underline, but using the following produces nothing.
$('body').on('keydown', function(e) {
   var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
   if(code == 13) {
      console.log($('body').find('a:active, a:focus'));
   }
})


Any reason you're doing it this way instead of using the built in tabindex attribute? That allows you to navigate the DOM using the Tab key, and activate links by pressing Return when the target link is focussed

@RoryMcCrossan thanks for your response. The sample code above is simply a dirty test to see if a link, highlighted by default browser behavior, is selectable by some pseudo class. I posted this question as part of a larger problem I asked here. The unordered list element is dynamically created by jQ UI Autocomplete plugin and the UI doesn't seem like one would naturally think to use a tab key to navigate. Up and down arrows seem more natural.

This should help
$('body').on('keydown', function(e) {
   var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
   if(code == 13) {
      var focusedLink = $('a:focus');
      console.log(focusedLink);
      focusedLink[0].click();
   }
});


Instead of var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which); you should use the preferred e.originalEvent.key and then, instead of using machine code like if(code == 13) { you use the more developer/human friendly: if (code === "Enter") {. Besides all that, one should prefer (if viable) the tabindex attribute. Also focusedLink[0].click(); is bug prone with possible errors like: "cannot access click property of undefined"... Also "This should help" is not the best way to document your answer.
